# Long building time with release configuration. is it normal?

Tags: compilation, linker, visual-studio-2013, intel-composer

I use the latest Intel compiler atop MVS 2013. I am developing a small application which currently consists of a static library with main functionality (9 classes) and an one-file console executable to test the former. I decided to build the application under release configuration to find out how faster it will become.

The problem is while the static library builds rather swiftly producing 13 MB .lib file (that is,as I found out, normal), the executable is taking very long time. I left it overnight and it is still hasn't been finished (currently over 12 hours). There has been no visible progress except mcpcom has been slowly increasing its memory usage to currently  1GB.

The static library compiling settings :

/MP /GS /GA /W3 /Gy /Zc:wchar_t /Zi /O2 /Fd"Release\vc120.pdb" /Qvec-report1 /D "WIN32" /D "NDEBUG" /D "_LIB" /D "_UNICODE" /D "UNICODE" /Qstd=c++11 /Qipo /Zc:forScope /Gd /Oi /MD /Fa"Release\" /EHsc /nologo /Fo"Release\" /Fp"Release\MyApplication_library.pch"

The executable compiling options:

/MP /GS /GA /W3 /Gy /Zc:wchar_t /I"C:\Work\MyApplication\MyApplication_library" /Zi /O2 /Fd"Release\vc120.pdb" /Qvec-report1 /D "_UNICODE" /D "UNICODE" /Qstd=c++11 /Qipo /Zc:forScope /Gd /Oi /MT /Fa"Release\" /EHsc /nologo /Fo"Release\" /Fp"Release\MyApplication_test.pch"

linker options

/OUT:"C:\Work\MyApplication\Release\MyApplication_test.exe" /MANIFEST /NXCOMPAT /PDB:"C:\Work\MyApplication\Release\MyApplication _test.pdb" /DYNAMICBASE "kernel32.lib" "user32.lib" "gdi32.lib" "winspool.lib" "comdlg32.lib" "advapi32.lib" "shell32.lib" "ole32.lib" "oleaut32.lib" "uuid.lib" "odbc32.lib" "odbccp32.lib" "C:\Work\Speedsim30\Release\MyApplication_Controller.lib" /LTCG:STATUS /MACHINE:X86 /OPT:REF /SAFESEH /MANIFESTUAC:"level='asInvoker' uiAccess='false'" /ManifestFile:"Release\MyApplication_test.exe.intermediate.manifest" /OPT:ICF /NOLOGO /TLBID:1

My personal computer has a powerful hardware configuration with Intel i7-4770K, 8 GB of DDR3-2133, and 2 SSDs in RAID0

thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out that the problem is in in /MT and /MD mismatch between the library and the executable -  i must have misclicked while setting up the release configuration. Correcting it allowed application to build.